# How can i straighten a hand drawn line in matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, corner-detection, image-morphology

[image: hand drawn line with irregularities]

I'm working on an image processing project where i need to detect corners. But when i try to detect corners using `corner` function, it detects the small displacements as corners as shown. [image: Wrong detection of corners]

I've tried with different thresholds from 0 to 0.24 and couldn't get food results.

```
imgskele = bwmorph(imgfill,'thin',Inf);
C = corner(imgspur, 'SensitivityFactor', 0.24);
figure; imshow(imgspur);
hold on;
plot(C(:,1), C(:,2),'bo','MarkerSize',10,'MarkerFaceColor','g');
hold off;
```

So i'm thinking of adjusting(redrawing) the line to make it straight line connecting those points

**Edit 1:**

Here are the full size original and output images:
[image]

Comment: Is it Peucker's algorithm you want maybe? Check Wikipedia Ramer–Douglas–Peucker algorithm

Comment: @MarkSetchell: Probably overkill here, but the basic idea is sensible.

Comment: Your *"starting image"* doesn't match your *"results image"* so it is hard to see what is causing OpenCV to think there are corners. Can you show the full start image that contains the *"corners"* please?

Comment: @MarkSetchell: I immediately thought OpenCV as well, but this isn't actually about OpenCV.

Comment: @MarkSetchell  i have updated the question, thanks

Answer (score 3):

The problem which you have is that the `corner` function is the Harris corner detector, which finds the corner of filled polygons.

Now a line can be approximated by a very thin polygon, certainly when pixelated, but that's not perfect as you notice here.

A more robust method is to use something like the Hough transform to find line features in the image. These lines will have intersections, some of which are approximately the corners you want. Others are fake intersections, because the Hough transform assumes lines and not line segments. You'll need to experiment a bit what you accept and what you reject. How rounded can a corner be, before you no longer call it a corner?

Comment: Thanks for the hint about Harris corner detector..  About hough transform I have already tried using hough transform to detect lines, but had faced same problem there also, due to hand-drawn nature of lines, not all lines were being detected. I've posted the question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36485935/how-to-detect-hand-drawn-lines-using-hough-transform-in-matlab

Thats why i tried to use corner detection so that i can connect corners to form straight lines between them which replace imperfect lines